# 421 Misdirect Request when jumping between subdomains

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Two subdomains have buttons to jump between them.
Jump is a very simple JS code:

```
window.location.href = 'https://xx.domain.com';
```

When opening these subdomains directly - everything ok. When jumping from another subdomain - got 421 Misdirect Request.

.htaccess for every subdomain:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Apache log says:

```
[Tue Apr 06 07:26:15 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 14706:tid 140278068365056] [client 178.140.186.3:61407] AH02032: Hostname en.unistex.com provided via SNI and hostname ru.unistex.com provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup, referer: https://en.unistex.com/
```

Don't understand - why incompatible?
Both subdomains protected by single domain certificate - it's enough to protect every subdomain when no jump.
All another SSL settings here are:

- HTTPS redirect - on
- OCSP stapling - on
- TLS 1.2+ Cipher Suite - on
  So, I've turned these settings to off separately and all together - no impact.

How to fix Apache error?

**UPDATE**:

SSL Manager at provider side tell me that `*.domain.com` certificate applied, so, I guess wildcards setup done when issue SSL certificate

Comment: Does anybody knows this problem?

Comment: Although it is an old question, I think that the solution published in this blog can be used by other members of the community. https://bobcares.com/blog/421-misdirected-request/

They makes it clear that the issue is generated by using the same SSL certificate across several subdomains, and I understand that the only strong solution is to issue independents SSL certify for each involved subdomains.